# Searching for text from column A in column B and output the row there is a match

Tags: excel

Column A has a list of cities. Column B has a list of addresses. And columns C-F have values. I want to search for the city (from column A) in column B and output the values for the row that contains the city from columns C-F.

I think it should be some sort of index match function, but I am not sure how to get the correct row number in this case. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like this:

```
IFERROR(FIND(A1,B1,1),NA())
```

[image]

you could then add an if() and concatenate C to F like this:

```
=if(IFERROR(FIND(A1,B1,1),NA())>0,C1&D1&E1&F1,"")
```

But only a guess since there is no example data.